# 4 en raya en java

Tags: java

vereis estoy haciendo un programa en java que consiste en el tipico 4 en raya de toda la vida.

El tema es que no tengo ni idea de como hacer para que cuando pulse uno de los botones que puse por columna, se pinte uno de otro color para que simule que se ha metido ficha, alguien sabe la idea de como hacerlo?

el codigo actual es este:

**interfaz**

```
public class Interfaz {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Marco miMarco = new Marco();
        miMarco.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

**Marco**

```
class Marco extends JFrame{

    public Marco() {

        setVisible(true);
        setTitle("4 en Raya");
        setSize(700, 620);
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        Tablero miTablero = new Tablero();
        add(miTablero);
        miTablero.updateUI();

    }

}
```

**Tablero**

```
class Tablero extends JPanel{

    private Image tablero;



    public Tablero() {

        try {

            tablero = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/mosaico.png"));

        }catch(IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 7));

        JButton boton1 = new JButton();
        JButton boton2 = new JButton();
        JButton boton3 = new JButton();
        JButton boton4 = new JButton();
        JButton boton5 = new JButton();
        JButton boton6 = new JButton();
        JButton boton7 = new JButton();

        add(boton1);
        boton1.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton2);
        boton2.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton3);
        boton3.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton4);
        boton4.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton5);
        boton5.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton6);
        boton6.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(boton7);
        boton7.setContentAreaFilled(false);

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(tablero, 0, 0, this);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como estas ocupando Swing, no tengo nada de conocimiento de él; sin embargo, sí que puedes crear `EventHandlers` o Manejadores de evento para cuando X acción ocurre, en este caso, un botón es presionado.

Algo así:

```
JButton boton1 = new JButton("Boton 1");

...

boton1.addActionListener(new ButtonListener()); 

class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Boton 1"))
            boton1.setContentAreaFilled(true);
        else if(ae.getActionCommand().equals("Boton 2"))
            boton1.setContentAreaFilled(true);
            //Y sigues asi con los botones...
    }
}
```

Te repito que nunca he tocado Java Swing, así que alguna sintaxis puede estar mal, pero toma esto como una base sobre la cual basarte, ok? :)

Te recomiendo [este video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCp7C2CuCRM) como ejemplo, del cual me basé, está en inglés pero, se entiende lo suficiente.

Buena suerte.

Comment: muchas gracias :)